# Elastic Search instance is crashing for version 8.8.1

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-firestore, elastic-stack, elastic-cloud

My project is using ElasticSearch and it is hosted in https://www.elastic.co/
However, the total amount of data is not so high, 1 ~ 2 GB.

The data is pushed into Elastic from Firestore using Firebase functions.

Sometimes the Elastic instances are crashing.

Here is the deployment.
[image]

Do you think we have not allocated enough resources in the Elastic Cloud?

Is there a case where the ElasticSearch instance crashes when we put in invalid data?

Comment: It would help to see the logs of the crashing instance